# Como receber conexões Cliente => Servidor, usando um software vpn?

Tags: cliente-servidor, vpn, redes

Eu tenho um software de acesso remoto (Cliente / Servidor) e quero fazer a conexão entre o Cliente (se conecta ao Servidor usando um nome de host) => Servidor usando um software vpn no lado do Servidor, mas isso não está funcionando.

A parte do servidor é semelhante a esta interface:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com base na minha investigação, é necessário configurar o ip do adaptador virtual do software vpn para o campo **DMZ** no meu modem, como mostrado abaixo na captura de tela. Acontece que o meu modem tem um validador de ip e não permite definir um ip de classe **A** (adaptador vpn), apenas um ip de classe **C**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O procedimento acima é padrão para este tipo de configuração (para conexões Cliente / Servidor).

> *OBS*: tudo funciona bem quando o **DMZ** está configurando com ip (classe **C**) do meu adaptador `Ethernet` (adaptador físico).

Então, com base no meu caso, como posso receber conexões Cliente => Servidor quando o PC (onde fica a parte Servidor) está "acessando a internet" através do software vpn (conexão vpn)?

Espero que eu tenha explicado bem o meu problema :-)

Comment: Votei para fechar esta pergunta pois, apesar de ser a favor de alguns temas de rede no site, esta pergunta foge completamente do escopo do site por se tratar de manuseio em um programa de terceiros e não de uma duvida teórica de redes que pode estar relacionado a programação.

Comment: @Articuno, dúvidas teóricas de redes qualquer 1 da área específica resolve sozinho, não é necessário pedir ajuda em fórum algum. Se você não entende do assunto desta questão ou algo assim, não atrapalha ok? Agradeço a compreenção.

Comment: O stackoverflow é um site voltado a duvidas de programação, sua duvida é sobre redes, o que foge do escopo do site. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Vocês de programação devem comentar/responder apenas à questões sobre programação, o que estão fazendo aqui?